# Recursive file search script only returns files of first subfolder

Tags: vba

First post here on Stackoverflow, let me know if do anything wrong.

I was working on a VBA script that returns a list of all files in a folder and it's subfolders. (in the form of a string)

However it returns only the files of the main folder and the first subfolder. This is really weird, because I can clearly see it looping through all folders, but somehow it is not returning the 'getfiles' variable for the other folders.

```
Sub test()
    MsgBox getfiles("L:\", True)
End Sub
```

Function:

```
Function getfiles(startFolder As String, doSubfolders As Boolean) As String
    Dim fso As New FileSystemObject
    Dim f As Folder, sf As Folder

    Set f = fso.GetFolder(startFolder)

    'loop through files
    For Each File In f.Files
        getfiles = getfiles & File.path & "|"
    Next

    'loop through subfolders
    If doSubfolders = True Then
        For Each sf In f.SubFolders
            getfiles = getfiles & getfiles(sf.path, doSubfolders)
        Next
    End If
End Function
```

Edit: Solved. Output was cutoff, likely due to msgbox chracter limit. Script just works.

Comment: Your code does the looping correctly but reports in different instances of the FileSystemObject. Do away with `Dim Fso As New Scripting.FileSystemObject` and you should be just fine.

Comment: You mean removing the dim statement? Tried that but then I get an 'object required' on the 4th line "Set f = fso.GetFolder(startFolder)"

Comment: No. it's the `New` keyword that's bothering me. The code given in the answer below looks more trustworthy to me. I haven't figured out all the logic but think it's worth trying.

Comment: Sorry, failed to read your comment correctly. Changed the dim statement but it didn't change anything? Also tried answer below, but doesn't change output as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just used late binding and its working for me, You may check out this code.

```
  Function getfiles(startFolder As String, doSubfolders As Boolean) As String
    Dim FSO As Object
Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.Filesystemobject")
    Dim f As Object, sf As Object

    Set f = FSO.GetFolder(startFolder)

    'loop through files
    For Each File In f.Files
        getfiles = getfiles & File.Path & "|"
    Next

    'loop through subfolders
    If doSubfolders = True Then
        For Each sf In f.SubFolders
            getfiles = getfiles & getfiles(sf.Path, doSubfolders)
        Next
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks, tried it but it didn't solve the problem.. The problem seems to be passing the results of a function back to the calling function. Because if I skip through the script it loops through all folders, but doesn't pass back the results for 2nd subfolder or subfolders of first subfolder.

Comment: I ran the code on 2 subfolders and 1 sub-sub folder . It is working if I call it from the worksheet as well as if I call it from the sub procedure. May be the problem was in object reference. What specific problem are you facing? Did you debug, where was the code misbehaving?

Comment: Tested it on another folder and it worked indeed, got back to the first folder and now noticed the text in the messagebox is cutoff, likely due to a msgbox character limit. Sorry for using your time, need more coffee next time I guess..

Answer (score 1):

to enhance what is already the solution, you should avoid instantiating FSO every time

```
Sub main()

    Dim FSO As Object
    Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.Filesystemobject") ' instantiate FSO once and for all

    Dim sFiles As String

    sFiles = GetFiles(FSO, "C:\...", True) ' pass instance of FSO, too

End Sub


Function GetFiles(FSO As Object, startFolder As String, doSubfolders As Boolean) As String ' accept FSO as argument
    Dim f As Object, sf As Object, file As Object

    Set f = FSO.GetFolder(startFolder) ' use passed instance of FSO

    'loop through files
    For Each file In f.Files
        GetFiles = GetFiles & file.Path & "|"
    Next

    'loop through subfolders
    If doSubfolders Then
        For Each sf In f.SubFolders
            GetFiles = GetFiles & GetFiles(FSO, sf.Path, doSubfolders) ' pass passed instance of FSO
        Next
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks. Is this solution using less time/resources?

Comment: you are welcome. Less resources for sure, which reflects on time execution: whether the actual gain may be relevant or not is up to the specific situation (how many subfolders, how big RAM etc..) but that remains a good coding practice